# Get a list of directory names with find

Tags: find, directory

I know I can do this to get a list of directory names:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1
```

The output looks like this:

```
.
./foo
./bar
```

I prefer the listing without `./`. Is there a way to get find to output just the raw names?

I tried sending the list to stat to format it but that just gives me the same result:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f '%N'
```

Comment: so you want `foo bar ...` all on one line without the `./` in front?

Comment: Is this purely for cosmetic / aesthetic reasons or are you trying to do something with the output?

Comment: a note that doesn't answer the question (already well answered): on recent versions of `find`, you will get a warning if you use a global option like `-maxdepth 1` after an argument like `-type d`; it is now recommended to reverse the order to `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Answer (score 74):

With GNU `find` you can use the `-printf` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

As noted by Paweł in the comments, if you don't want the current directory to be listed add `-mindepth 1`, e.g.:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: I cannot find any mention of the `-printf` option in [the latest POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and I wonder how portable it is ...

Comment: @rahmu: This was tested with GNU find. None of the `printf` options are mentioned by POSIX and they do not seem to be supported by some of the other `find` versions. GNU find can be installed in most places, so in that sense it is portable.

Comment: also add `-mindepth 1` if you want to get rid of the `.`

Answer (score 23):

Update:

A shorter alternative:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -c 3-
```

Will give you the names, one per line, without any slashes

Comment: @downvoter ..  a downvote ***without*** explanation doesn't help *anyone* (OP, SO or me). This is a functional solution to OP's question. I am happy to correct an error if pointed out or improve the answer, but that requires *constructive* feedback rather than just an anonymous "click".

Comment: I'm the one who downvoted when your answer included parsing `ls`. At the same time I had posted a link on [why this is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on another answer that got deleted since. At the time there were only 2 answers and the reason seemed obvious. I'm glad you pointed out the ambiguity, and here's my explanation. For the record, I turned my downvote in an upvote because I agree with your current answer.

Comment: @rahmu Giving an explanation for your downvote in ***another*** question is not helpful to me (and only obvious to you). Also, while this is a better solution, the solution I had posted before worked just fine (yes, I am familiar with your "don't use ls" link - but it doesn't apply blindly in all cases). If you have a counter example for why my initial solution wouldn't have worked, I'd love to know it (so that I can actually learn something from this), otherwise you are just posting a link and not offering anything constructive.

Comment: Consider there's a `\n` in a directory name you cannot use cut to retrieve it (which is what you were doing when I downvoted you). There are few cases where `ls` doesn't behave dangerously and it's almost always safer to use another way.

Answer (score 9):

Using GNU find, you can use -mindepth to prevent find from matching the current directory:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```

Since you are not doing this recursively, you can use a bash glob:

```
echo */
```

Adding a trailing / to a glob will cause only directories to be matched.

Comment: `*/` misses dot files and includes symlinks. This may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @Gilles - It will always miss symlinks, but dotfiles depends on whether or not dotglob is set.

Answer (score 8):

I'd rather use:

```
 find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 6):

Let `sed` remove those two characters:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed -e 's/^\.\///'
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use:

```
find * -type d
```

But I don't know if it's the right way to do what you want.

Comment: If you are going to let the shell expand all the filenames, why use find at all?

Comment: @jordanm To select only directories. `echo */` would do the same thing, more or less (it misses dot files and includes symlinks), but then joachim would ask how to remove the final `/`.

Comment: Contrary to other answers, a "find *" will miss any "hidden dirs" (dirs whose name starts with a .)

Answer (score 0):

In AIX does the parameter 'maxdepth' not work.

In general this works for me:

`find ./ -type d | cut -d"/" -f2 | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `basename`, it ignore the unix directory structure

**Example below:**

`find /any/path/you/want -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;`

it will exclude for the output even the dir path, removing the necessity to `cd`  before run the command

---

Some aditional info:

I'd pass `-exec` as argument to find instead `|`(pipe) another command for the output (avoiding the second command go over each output line, having said that, depending on the output it could improve the performance for the script)

NOTE: `find` options are  **not positional** (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

```
find * -type d -maxdepth 0
```