# How to use find command to list file names but not path?

Tags: find

I've checked some answers online, but they do not work when there's a `-name` parameter in the command (maybe I'm doing something wrong, not sure). What I'd like to do is to list only filenames (not the directory/path), and to complicate more, I have same filename with different extension, so I need to filter the result using `-name` and `-o`, the trouble is the suggestions that I saw use either `-printf` or `basename`, and those doesn't work well when there's `-name *.txt -o name *.pdf`. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Example of my files:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
                    /file1.txt
                    /file1.pdf
                    /file1.ods ...etc.
```

I'm only interested in listing one or more type of file per listing (by using `-name` to filter my results.

Is it possible to accomplish it using only 1 `find` command or I have to do it in 2 steps (saving the result in a temporary file, then filter/strip the directory from the temp file)? The result I'm trying to accomplish is a text file with filename per line:

```
file1.txt
file1.pdf
file1.ods
file2.txt
file2.pdf
etc.
```

The command I was using is

```
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.ods' -printf "%f\n"
```

I am using GNU find.

**Update**

It turned out I have to put `\(...\)`, as reminded by αғsнιη

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70618/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46259/117549 in the case of GNU find...

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thanks for your feedback, yes, I'm using GNU find, I've tried that, but when I used `-printf` and `-name *.txt -o -name *.pdf` it'll list only the last one, not both, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm not that familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using multiple expressions in logical OR mode with `-o` you need enclose them all within `\( ... \)`, else the last expression result is always respected; and `-printf '%f\n'` is used to print the files' name only with any leading directories removed.

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.txt' \) -printf '%f\n'
```

see [`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) under *OPERATORS* section about `( expr )`:

> OPERATORS
> ...
>
> ( expr )
> Force precedence.  Since parentheses are special to the shell, you will normally need to quote them.

so you can either use `\( ... \)` or `'(' ... ')'` (whitespaces after and before parenthesis are important) to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, you need to group your `-name` tests in parentheses.  These parentheses need to be escaped as `\( ... \)` or quoted as e.g. `'(' ... ')'` to protect them from the shell (where they would otherwise designate a subshell).

Using standard `find`, and also making handling the filename suffixes slightly easier:

```bsh
set -- txt pdf ods

for suffix do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
    shift
done
shift

find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4 \( "$@" \) -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

This first sets the positional parameters to the list of filename suffixes that we'd like to see (this could also be taken from the command line if this is a script), and constructs the OR-list of `-name` tests. This is then used in the `find` command line.

The the `find` command itself then calls the `basename` utility for each found name.

As an alternative, we could instead use a parameter substitution to remove all but the filename component of each pathname, but to do so we must pass the pathnames to an inline `sh -c` script:

```bsh
# [...] as before [...]

find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4 \( "$@" \) -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "%s\n" "${pathname##*/}"
    done' sh {} +
```

I would expect this to run quicker than the variation using `basename`, at least if there are many filenames to handle, although with GNU `basename` from coreutils, you could use `-a` or `--multiple` likes so:

```bsh
find /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4 \( "$@" \) -type f -exec basename -a {} +
```

This would call `basename` as few times as possible.  But then again, if you had coreutils installed, you may well have findutils too, with GNU `find`, and could use `-printf '%f\n'` to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks αғsнιη and Kusalananda for your feedback and detailed explanation, it's much appreciated. With Linux, you never stops learning.